# Are there any online resources for finding the signaling pathways that two proteins both belong to?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, database, cell-signaling, pathway

I am studying the proteins GSK3 and AMPK and I am trying to identify the signaling pathways that both of these proteins belong to. From reading journal papers I have found out that both of these proteins belong to the mTOR signaling pathway. I know on [KEGG](https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?hsa04150) if you type the name of a gene involved in a signaling pathway (e.g. GSK3B) in the search bar on the page showing a signaling pathway (e.g. the mTOR pathway), you can find more information about that gene. However, I was wondering if there are any resources online where you can type the names of multiple genes and you can find out the signaling pathways that all of the genes are in?

Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try **"gsk3" AND "AMPK"** at [WikiPathways](https://www.wikipathways.org/index.php/WikiPathways) .

Here are [some pathways where both GSK3 and AMPK are participants](https://www.wikipathways.org//index.php?query=%22gsk3%22+AND+%22AMPK%22&species=ALL+SPECIES&title=Special%3ASearchPathways&doSearch=1&ids=&codes=&type=query), such as:

[image: pathway]

And
[image: Molecules]